# SSRS Exact copy of a table does not stay within the page

Tags: reporting-services

I am trying to set up a 3 part check where the header of the report is the check itself, and the next 2 sections are each a table with the detail data. One copy stays here while the other goes with the check as a stub. I want the data to be exactly the same and print on the same page. The problem I am having is that if I print 2 checks the second table does not appear on the first page but shows up on the second page with the second check (2 tables in the bottom of the second page). How do I get the second table to print on the page with the proper check? I have put both into a rectangle in the body but that has not helped.

I also need the second table to be in a specific location on the page so it can't be put into the first table since the number of detail rows may vary.

Comment: Impossible to tell what the problem is without more info. Please share you report design and a sample of what output you are getting now (even if's it's just a sketched mock-up)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got it working! Here is what I did.
1 - Created a subreport that holds the copy of the first table
2 - Added 2 rows below the detail group and put it outside of the group
3 - Put the subreport on the second added row
4 - Made the first added row below the detail big enough to force the subreport to be on the page where I want it.

Here is what the rdl looks like in report builder
[image]

Answer (score 0):

How do I share the report design when I can't upload files? It's also hard to get a 2 page pdf file into a single snapshot. The image I uploaded is the second page. The second table should be on the first page not the second page.
The other issue with this is that my page header is expecting to find a total of the fields in the table, so if I use 2 subreports and remove the tables it can't calculate the total.

[image: Shapshot of output]

Comment: You should make a table with two groupings - one for detail and another for the check. Use the group header row(s) for your check and the detail for the individual line items. Set the group to New Page at Start of group.

Comment: How or where would the second table go? I need the exact same data twice on the page. The detail data can be different from check to check  but I need the format the same.

Answer (score 0):

I am still confused as to what to do. The ultimate goal is to have the check print like this (works fine if only printing one check):
[image]

Here is a snapshot of what my rdl looks like in report builder:
[image]

I want the exact same table repeated on the same page. I have tried putting them both in a rectangle but that didn't work. I have tried making the second table a subreport but that didn't work. I have tried making 2 subreports with each containing a table but that didn't work. The check part of it is in the page header and it uses the sum of the data from the table to get the total check amount.

Answer (score 0):

Very helpful for providing direction for my own Epicor report customization. My check portion is at the bottom so I had to put my subreport at the top. I had to hide the detail of the main report and replace it with a second subreport because I couldn't figure out how to keep the top section the same height as the number of invoice rows changed. Using the subreport copy took care of this.

A couple of details about my subreport creation...

- copied the main report and stripped out everything but the main tablix/details
- added a parameter for "checknum", then also applied that parameter to the group filters